# How did “admettre” semantically generalize to signify “confess”?

Tags: étymologie, latin

McWhorter, J. [PhD  Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter). [*The Power of Babel* (2003)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006052085X). p. 32 Bottom.

> Semantic drift has an especially visible effect on combinations
>   of roots and prefixes or suffixes, and this effect, too, creates important differences between a language and the one it turns into. Our
>   French sentence’s *admettez-le* “ admit it” is a good example of this
>   kind of development. *Admettre* is composed of *ad-*, a preservation of
>   the full word or prefix for “to” in Latin, and *mettre* “ to put.” This
>   verb had an ancestor in Latin, but this Latin verb *admittere* did not
>   mean “ to confess,” which was conveyed with other verbs like
>   *agnoscere*. Instead, the main meaning of *admittere* was the literal one
>   of “ putting or sending into.” 'The “ confess” meaning of its French
>   descendant arrived gradually by the same kind of hanging implication that created French’s *have*-perfect: **to admit something is to give
>   it entree into—that is, “put it into”—your acknowledged awareness. [My emboldening]**

I understand that “admettre” originally signfied “put to”, but how did it generalize to: put to “your acknowledged awareness”?  The author doesn't expound.

*Put to* itself doesn't suggest “your acknowledged awareness”. One can “put to” many other things, if this makes sense. So what narrowed *put to* to “your acknowledged awareness”?

Answer (score 3):

I'm by no mean linguist, but being french I may be able to help.

I think `to confess` is a misleading translation, I can't think of a sentence where it could be exactly used as such. The closest would be "Admettre ses erreurs" *(To admit/accept/acknowledge your errors)*; which is more introspective than confessing.

A better example of "to give entree into your acknowledged awareness" would be the use of `admettre` to accept something as true:

> "J'admets que tu as raison" *(I admit you are right)*

You can also use it before an hypothesis at the start of a sentence; to signify we consider this hypothesis as true:

- "Admettons que tu arrives à 20h chez moi, on aura jamais le temps d'y être à 20h30!" *(Let's say you arrive at my place at 20h, we won't have time to be there at 20h30!)*
- "Si on admet que le voyage dans le temps est possible, pourquoi ne pas tuer les parents de Sarah Connor ?" *(Let's say time travel is possible, why not killing Sarah Connor's parents ?)*

Hope this helped.

Comment: We generally wouldn't use *confesser* instead of *admettre* but in English, that might be the case: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/confess